# MSword in a web browser or any other server control that has ruler in it

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am developing asp.net with c#web application.
I want to have a control in ASP.net that has text formatting controls as well as a ruler to edit the text which i enter in text area. It would be great if i can open Msword in a web browser without Save buttons at the client side.The data must be saved into the database.

The control should be similar to the one which i get while writing this question.and also e.g gmail compose mail.

My main aim is to provide right and left indentation to the text that is being entered and i want to preview on A4 size paper.

Please guide me someone the way to proceed.I got Htmleditor ajax control but it doesnot have a ruler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) (this is what you are using for typing this question). You could also take a look at the [many other alternative editors](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=25657,25980,26637,26992,27095,27178&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=wysiwyg+html+editor&cp=8&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=active&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=wysiwyg+&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=499faa430ac3503f) and pick one that suits your needs.

Comment: I want a ruler or any tool which can provide right indentation without disturbing left indentation.